# How do I transform a large number of commits in a git repository

Tags: git, svn

I have a git repository that has been converted from subversion. In the subversion repository part of the tree was imported using revision-pegged externals and the conversion tool left information on how to find these externals in a file in the repository.

Now I want to rewrite the git repository to include the files from the subversion externals.

I think the way to do this is to locate all places where the meta file changes, export the externals from subversion and commit the changes to the files in the git repository. Am I on the right track? If so, how can I do this with git and if not, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that I can use `git filter-branch` to rewrite each commit in a repository using a script, so I wrote a script that reads the externals meta-file and uses `svn export` to add the files included by the externals.